# Trying to install Operator Lifecycle Manager (OLM) in my EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, operator-lifecycle-manager

I tried to install Operator Lifecycle Manager in my EC2 instance and I get the authentication error.

```
curl -sL https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-lifecycle-manager/releases/download/v0.25.0/install.sh | bash -s v0.25.0
```

Following is the error from the EC2 instance.

> ```
> ubuntu@ip****:~$ curl -sL https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-lifecycle-manager/releases/download/v0.25.0/install.sh | bash -s v0.25.0
> ```
>
> ```
> .Error from server (Forbidden): <html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2Fswagger-2.0.0.pb-v1%3Ftimeout%3D32s'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2Fswagger-2.0.0.pb-v1%3Ftimeout%3D32s');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>
>
> Authentication required
> <!--
> -->
> ```

I want to install the Operator Lifecycle Manager so that I can Kubernetes cluster and ArgoCD.

Comment: I was able to download script from github ... i.e. `curl -sL https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-lifecycle-manager/releases/download/v0.25.0/install.sh` works fine. Most probably you need configure `kubectl`